# Eagerly stop an Akka-Stream Source

Tags: akka-stream

I have the following (simplified) consumer that is supposed to cancel an Akka-Stream (2.11_2.5-SNAPSHOT of today) `Source` after the first item but the `onNext` is still getting called 4 times:

```
static Subscriber<Object> println() {
    return new Subscriber<Object>() {

        Subscription s;

        int n;

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            this.s = s;
            s.request(5);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object t) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                  + ": " + t + " - " + (++n));
            if (s != null) {
                s.cancel();
                s = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": DONE");
        }
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Config cfg = ConfigFactory.parseResources(
        AkkaRange.class, "/akka-streams.conf").resolve();
    ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("sys", cfg);

    ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(actorSystem);

    Source<Integer, NotUsed> source = Source.repeat(1);

    Publisher<Integer> p = source.runWith(Sink.asPublisher(
         AsPublisher.WITH_FANOUT), materializer);

    p.subscribe(println());

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    actorSystem.terminate();
}
```

Given that request is 5 yet only 4 calls are made, I assume the underlying messaging architecture responds to requests in 4-batches before checking the message queue for a cancellation (or further request) messages.

*Is there a setting to make the cancellation happen more eagerly?*

The use case is something like an **interop** computation where there is a computationally intensive stage (map) that may produce a desired result after 1-2 source elements and the downstream cancels the stream in this case. The problem is that due to this 4 batch, the computation is executed for the remaining 2-3 elements too.

Comment: It's a fairness issue. Doing long running computations in `map` may block some signals from being registered eagerly. There are two potential solutions: either 1) use `mapAsync` instead and run the long running computation offside or 2) lower `actor.stream.materializer.sync-processing-limit` to make sure external signals are handled faster (will disadvantage throughput, though).

Comment: Thanks, they seem to be reasonable options. Will go with option 2 for now as there is no other Akka Stream requiring throughput. Could you post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `Subscriber` interface is [a part of](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.0/README.md#2-subscriber-code) the Reactive Streams specification, which lots of libraries, akka-streams included, implement. And this specification states the following thing:

> A Subscriber MUST be prepared to receive one or more onNext signals after having called Subscription.cancel() if there are still requested elements pending [see 3.12]. Subscription.cancel() does not guarantee to perform the underlying cleaning operations immediately.

Therefore you have to handle this situation in your subscriber manually, otherwise it would be violating the specification and thus unfit to be used with the libraries implementing the spec.

Comment: I know the spec to the letter and if it were my Subscriber only, I'd ignore further onNexts. The problem is that the heavy computation is done on the Akka Stream side in a plain map() operation that gets executed 4 times instead of once. I have no control over the implementation of the function of the map(). Also being eager with cancellation, like Rx, doesn't violate the spec.

Comment: @akarnokd did you issue `request(5)` and then `cancel` in your subscriber?